# firstResponder is not getting set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, first-responder

After a `UITextField` is edited and return is pressed, I loop through and check for the next field.  I get the index path of that field, then save it. Next I reload table data and when the table is being built, if the `indexPath` is equal to the `indexPath` of what would be the next text field, then I set it as first responder.

I grab the correct `textField` at the correct `indexPath` and everything, however first responder doesn't get set.  Instead, focus just disappears.

My code:

```
//inside UITextFieldShouldReturn

for (int i = uiTextField.fieldTag + 1; i < group.fields.count; i++) {
ObjectEditField *field = [group.fields objectAtIndex:i];
     if (field.propName && field.updateObjectOnEdit == YES && [field isKindOfClass:[ObjectEditTextField class]]) {
        // set the active field
        activeField = field;

       // obtain a pointer to the textfield object and set it to be the first responder
         ObjectEditTextField *textField = (ObjectEditTextField *)field;
         if (![textField.field isFirstResponder]) {
         UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[uiTextField superview] superview] superview];
         firstResponderIndexPath = [_fieldsTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Then once I have the `firstResponderIndexPath` I call `reloadData` on the table view, and inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I have:

```
if (firstResponderIndexPath.row + 1 == indexPath.row)
{
    ObjectEditTextField *textField = (ObjectEditTextField *)field;
    NSLog(@"display: %@", textField.field.text);
    [textField.field becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

The output for the `NSLog` is correct and the field it should be.  However the first responder doesn't get set correctly.

Comment: Please don't create the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set the first responder if the view is part of the view hierarchy of the window.  "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" gets called before it is added. So you'll have to set the first responder after the cells have been added, e.g. after you call reloadData in your UITableViewController subclass:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
MyTableCell *cell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: firstResponderIndexPath];
[cell.myTextFieldProperty becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: this solution didn't work either.

Comment: what is the result of becomeFirstResponder? YES or NO?

Comment: BOOL result = [textField.myTextFieldProperty becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: NSLog( @"result: %@", @(result));

Comment: NSLog( @"text field: %@", textField.myTextFieldProperty);

Comment: The last one is for checking the class of the text field, just to be sure.

Comment: becomeFirstResponder returns no.   I'm assuming this is the root of the issue?

Comment: yes, probably. Please post the following log output:

Comment: NSLog( @"text field: %@", textField.myTextFieldProperty);

Comment: NSLog( @"delegate: %@", textField.myTextFieldProperty.delegate);

Comment: text field: <ObjectEditBaseTextField: 0x23cc1ca0; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (0 0; 245 24); text = '7'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x23cc2140>; layer = <CALayer: 0x23cc1830>>
delegate: <ObjectEditTextField: 0x23cc1760; frame = (0 0; 245 24); layer = <CALayer: 0x23cc1800>>

Answer (score 0):

Has the cell been added to the window at the point where you are calling `becomeFirstResponder`?  If it is not, nothing will happen.  From the docs:

> **becomeFirstResponder**
>
> You may call this method to make a responder object such as a view the first responder. However, you should only call it on that view if it is part of a view hierarchy. If the view’s window property holds a UIWindow object, it has been installed in a view hierarchy; if it returns nil, the view is detached from any hierarchy.

Try calling it in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` instead.  You could also set a boolean property on the desired cell and have it call `becomeFirstResponder` on its field in `didMoveToSuperview`.

Comment: I moved my if check to the method you mentioned but no dice.  same effect is happening.

Comment: Did you try using the cell's `didMoveToSuperview`?

Comment: how do you use a cell's didMoveToSuperview?

Comment: Implement `didMoveToSuperview` in a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and add two properties: something like `BOOL shouldAutomaticallyBecomeFirstResponder` and `UITextField inputField.  In `didMoveToSuperview`, check if that property is `YES` then call `becomeFirstResponder` on `inputField`.

Comment: just implemented this.  no change.  didMoveToSuperView never gets called after a user submits to a textfield.  only when the cells display for the first time.